# Testcontainers + db2 issue

Tags: java, db2, testcontainers

I am having an issue with db2 using testcontainers. I keep receiving a connection refused error.

When running db2 with:

- `docker run` I am able to connect with dbvis.
- using fabric8 maven plugin to start the db2 container and again I am able to connect with dbvis

I put a breakpoint in the junit5 test and attempt access db2 and I receive the connection refused.

My db2 testcontainers configuration:

```
@Testcontainers
public class ArchiveTest {

    @Container
    private static final Db2Container DB2 = new Db2Container("ibmcom/db2:11.5.7.0").withPrivilegedMode(true)
            .acceptLicense().withUsername("db2inst1").withPassword("password").withDatabaseName("BPMF")
            .withEnv("ARCHIVE_LOGS", "false").withEnv("PERSISTENT_HOME", "false");
```

The db2 logs from docker:

```
(*) Previous setup has not been detected. Creating the users...
(*) Creating users ...
(*) Creating instance ...

DB2 installation is being initialized.

Total estimated time for all tasks to be performed: 309 second(s)
 Total number of tasks to be performed: 4
Estimated time 1 second(s)
Description: Setting default global profile registry variables
Task #1 start

Task #1 end
Estimated time 5 second(s)
Description: Initializing instance list
Task #2 start

Task #2 end
Estimated time 300 second(s)
Description: Configuring DB2 instances
Task #3 start

Task #3 end

The execution completed successfully.

Task #4 end
Estimated time 3 second(s)
Description: Updating global profile registry
Task #4 start
For more information see the DB2 installation log at "/tmp/db2icrt.log.72".
(*) Fixing /etc/services file for DB2 ...


DBI1070I  Program db2icrt completed successfully.


DBI1446I  The db2icrt command is running.
chown: cannot access '/database/config/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/fencedid': No such file or directory
03/16/2022 10:26:18     0   0   SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019
(*) Cataloging existing databases
(*) Applying Db2 license ...
ls: cannot access /database/data/db2inst1/NODE0000: No such file or directory

LIC1426I  This product is now licensed for use as outlined in your License Agreement.  USE OF THE PRODUCT CONSTITUTES ACCEPTANCE OF THE TERMS OF THE IBM LICENSE AGREEMENT, LOCATED IN THE FOLLOWING DIRECTORY: "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/license/en_US.iso88591"

LIC1402I  License added successfully.

(*) Updating DBM CFG parameters ...
(*) Saving the checksum of the current nodelock file ...
successfully.
DB20000I  The UPDATE DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION command completed
successfully.
DB20000I  The UPDATE DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION command completed
successfully.
DB20000I  The UPDATE DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION command completed
(*) Remounting /database with suid...
No Cgroup memory limit detected, instance memory will follow automatic tuning
(*) Nothing appears in the Db2 directory. will skip update/upgrade.
(*) Code level is the same. No update/upgrade needed.
DB2 State : Operable


Starting DB2...
DB2 has not been started
SQL1063N  DB2START processing was successful.
03/16/2022 10:26:29     0   0   SQL1063N  DB2START processing was successful.
(*) Creating database BPMF ...
(*) User chose to create BPMF database
DB20000I  The CREATE DATABASE command completed successfully.
DB20000I  The ACTIVATE DATABASE command completed successfully.
(*) Instance and database will not be auto configured. AUTOCONFIG has been set to false.
(*) Log archiving will not be configured as ARCHIVE_LOGS has been set to false.
(*) Skipping TEXT_SEARCH setup for database BPMF because TEXT_SEARCH is not configured for the instance ...
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA1 RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519
(*) All databases are now active.
(*) Setup has completed.
2022-03-16 12:27:28 | INFO  | [main] d.5.7.0]:503 - Container ibmcom/db2:11.5.7.0 started in PT1M27.212S
```

The error from java is:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.25.13] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server /127.0.0.1 on port 50,000 with message: Connection refused: connect. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:338)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:435)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.a(a0.java:445)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.<init>(a0.java:96)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.b(a.java:366)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.newAgent_(b.java:2148)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.initConnection(Connection.java:839)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:784)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:350)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:200)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:471)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:113)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.osjava.datasource.SJDataSource.getConnection(SJDataSource.java:115)
        at org.osjava.datasource.SJDataSource.getConnection(SJDataSource.java:106)
        at org.osjava.datasource.SJDataSource.getConnection(SJDataSource.java:88)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48)
        ... 105 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.x.run(x.java:49)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.a(a0.java:431)
        ... 121 common frames omitted


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'migration' threw exception; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.25.13] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server /127.0.0.1 on port 50,000 with message: Connection refused: connect. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

I have confirmed my JDBC parameters are correct...so I am at a bit of a loss where it is going wrong.

EDIT 1: db2 is running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                          NAMES
e7046334e6c8   ibmcom/db2:11.5.0.0a        "/var/db2_setup/lib/…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   22/tcp, 55000/tcp, 60006-60007/tcp, 0.0.0.0:53444->50000/tcp   wizardly_cartwright
ccfe6845bfb1   testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3   "/app"                   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:53439->8080/tcp                                        testcontainers-ryuk-99222438-9340-47ca-b6d2-0a13bfe50f9d
```

EDIT2: docker-for-java command parameters:

```
AbstrDockerCmd:34 - Cmd: org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.CreateContainerCmdImpl@7df60067[name=<null>,hostName=<null>,domainName=<null>,user=<null>,attachStdin=<null>,attachStdout=<null>,attachStderr=<null>,portSpecs=<null>,tty=<null>,stdinOpen=<null>,stdInOnce=<null>,env={DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1,AUTOCONFIG=false,ARCHIVE_LOGS=false,DB2INST1_PASSWORD=password,PERSISTENT_HOME=false,DBNAME=BPMF,LICENSE=accept},cmd={},healthcheck=<null>,argsEscaped=<null>,entrypoint=<null>,image=ibmcom/db2:11.5.0.0a,volumes=Volumes(volumes=[]),workingDir=<null>,macAddress=<null>,onBuild=<null>,networkDisabled=<null>,exposedPorts=ExposedPorts(exposedPorts=[50000/tcp]),stopSignal=<null>,stopTimeout=<null>,hostConfig=HostConfig(binds=[], blkioWeight=null, blkioWeightDevice=null, blkioDeviceReadBps=null, blkioDeviceWriteBps=null, blkioDeviceReadIOps=null, blkioDeviceWriteIOps=null, memorySwappiness=null, nanoCPUs=null, capAdd=null, capDrop=null, containerIDFile=null, cpuPeriod=null, cpuRealtimePeriod=null, cpuRealtimeRuntime=null, cpuShares=null, cpuQuota=null, cpusetCpus=null, cpusetMems=null, devices=null, deviceCgroupRules=null, deviceRequests=null, diskQuota=null, dns=null, dnsOptions=null, dnsSearch=null, extraHosts=[], groupAdd=null, ipcMode=null, cgroup=null, links=[], logConfig=LogConfig(type=null, config=null), lxcConf=null, memory=null, memorySwap=null, memoryReservation=null, kernelMemory=null, networkMode=null, oomKillDisable=null, init=null, autoRemove=null, oomScoreAdj=null, portBindings={50000/tcp=[Lcom.github.dockerjava.api.model.Ports$Binding;@393881f0}, privileged=true, publishAllPorts=null, readonlyRootfs=null, restartPolicy=null, ulimits=null, cpuCount=null, cpuPercent=null, ioMaximumIOps=null, ioMaximumBandwidth=null, volumesFrom=[], mounts=null, pidMode=null, isolation=null, securityOpts=null, storageOpt=null, cgroupParent=null, volumeDriver=null, shmSize=null, pidsLimit=null, runtime=null, tmpFs=null, utSMode=null, usernsMode=null, sysctls=null, consoleSize=null),labels={org.testcontainers=true, org.testcontainers.sessionId=090442b0-8cc4-4f6e-b07e-1afdfed5ec15},shell=<null>,networkingConfig=<null>,ipv4Address=<null>,ipv6Address=<null>,aliases=<null>,authConfig=<null>,platform=<null>]
```

---

As I am using smplie-jndi and have the JDBC parameters in property files, the port for the JDBC URL is not 50000. Busy looking how to set it to a specific port as the default is specified in the DB2Container class

EDIT 1: It's mentioned in the docs

```
Note that this exposed port number is from the perspective of the container.

From the host's perspective Testcontainers actually exposes this on a random free port. This is by design, to avoid port collisions that may arise with locally running software or in between parallel test runs.
```

Comment: And Db2 is already up and running when you try to connect?

Comment: From the logs I believe it is

Comment: A DB2 container takes some time to start up with all services. I would suggest your testing app waits for a couple of minutes before initiating connections.

Comment: OS is windows...I've posted the values from the AbstractDockerCmd in EDIT 2. I've not defined a network share.

Comment: @TheImpaler Testcontainers waits till this regex `".*Setup has completed\\..*"` is found in the logs before the junit test continues

Comment: Do you connect using `DB2.getJdbcUrl()` ? seems the port number (50000) is wrong, tc uses randomized ports

Comment: @nfgl I don't. There are config files for simple-jndi to register the datasource. I'll define the port number and see if that makes a difference

Comment: @nfgl default port of 50,000 is specified in the db2 container object.

Comment: This is the internal container port, not the port on which the container will be accessible from the host.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to use `DB2.getJdbcUrl()` or similar access the container after starting it. Testcontainers publishes the exposed ports of the container to a random free host port and this dynamic port needs to be injected into your system under test at runtime. Depending on framework and libraries, there are different ways to achieve these, either configuration properties in Spring, or worst case, by templating config files.